# Create public function for updating sales_order data Magento2.3

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Help, please!

I'm using **Magento 2.3** and I am trying to update **`sales_order`** table **`data`** programmatically.

What's the best way to implement it?

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: solve this using **`Observer`** for `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this below code in your controller. You can use `OrderRepositoryInterface` to load and `ResourceModel` to save order.

```
protected $orderResourceModel;
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResourceModel
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderResourceModel = $orderResourceModel;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    ....
}

public function execute()
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get(1); //1 is your order ID
    $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW);
    $order->setCustomerEmail('test@test.com');
    $this->orderResourceModel->save($order);
}
```

Comment: what if I want to update not the email but a custom column field? @Rohan Hapani